# 301 redirect of rewritten pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-redirect

I'm moving an existing projet from root to language folder /fr, in order to create a different english project located in /en.

The project is simple, it consists on two pages (index.php and liste.php).
The first page was receiving a parameter

```
/index.php?hash=[page-hash]
```

and was rewriten in the .htaccess as

```
/[page-hash].html
```

So here is the content of the old .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
#########   Page rewriting  ########
RewriteRule ^liste\.html$           liste.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$            index.php?hash=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I want the old rewritten pages (www.domain.com/[page-hash].html), which are indexed by Google, to be 301 redirected to www.domain.com/fr/[page-hash].html so that Google still find them at new new location and is informed it has been moved.

It's not a rewriting, it's a redirect, and I don't know how to do that. I guess I have to use RewriteCond and [R=301] but I don't know how.

Of course the new pages must also be rewritten (/fr/index.php?hash=[page-hash] into /fr/[page-hash].html), and the root generally redirected to /fr. So I already made this new .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
######## Redirect from root to /fr #######
RewriteRule ^$                      /fr 
Redirect 301 /liste.html            /fr/liste.html
Redirect 301 /liste.php             /fr/liste.html
#########   Page rewriting  ########
RewriteRule ^fr/liste\.html$        /fr/liste.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)\.html$         /fr/index.php?hash=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/list\.html$         /en/list.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)\.html$         /en/index.php?hash=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I got it, at least part of it. I use [R] for a redirect rule, and apply it on liste.html `RewriteRule  ^liste\.html$  /fr/liste.html [QSA,R,L]` with a [L] instruction so that its ignore the next rules.Only then, I also use a [R] rule to redirect the other pages : `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /fr/index.php?hash=$1 [QSA,R]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close. You can condense those and you only need `QSA` (and `B`) when your substitution contains a query.

```
RewriteEngine On
######## Redirect from root to /fr #######
RewriteRule ^$ /fr/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.(?:html|php)$ /fr/$1.html [L,R=301]
######### Page rewriting ########
RewriteRule ^(fr/liste|en/list)\.html$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(fr|en)/([^/]+)\.html$ $1/index.php?hash=$2 [L,B,QSA]
```

Comment: Op wants to redirect old urls to the new format eg : **/path/?q=foo** to **/foo** QSA is not the solution here.

Comment: Thanks but it's not the solution. To express it differently, I want to apply two rules successively. First, this one (redirect): `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$  /fr/index.php?hash=$1 [R=301]` AND THEN this one (rewriting): `RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)\.html$  /fr/index.php?hash=$1 [QSA,L]`. The lasting problem is that it must apply this rule to all hashes but not to /liste.html neither /liste.php.

Comment: The first two rules *are* redirects, that's what `R=301` does. It redirects from old pretty URL to new pretty URL, like it should. Did you try them?

Comment: @starkeen you've got it back to front.

Comment: @bolino you're mistaken, you don't expose your internal URL structure in an external redirect.

Comment: @Walf Yes, [R=301] is definitly is part of the solution. I tried but  http://domain.com/fr/liste.html and http://domain.com/fr/liste.php are rewritten in an infinite server path (probably the rewriting rule of the hash page is applied to them while it shouldn't). And pages with hash don't get the parameter (that, I don't get why).

Comment: @Walf Yes, it shouldn't be exposed, you're right. But I don't get how to to both (the redirect + the rewriting) in one line.

Comment: ...without "liste" charset be mistaken as a hash.

Comment: I have updated my answer; sorry, I was lazy. Rewrite means transform the URL in some way but doesn't decide what action to take. With `R`, the action is ‘send transformed URL to the client so they make a new request with it’. Without `R` the action is ‘use my transformed URL as the real one, without letting the client know’. It's then up to the server to resolve this "real" URL. It will pass the new URL through all those rules again, as if it were a new request (up to 10 times by default). This is why you should be careful that rewritten URLs won't match again and cause an infinite loop.

Comment: OK, I got it, thanks to you. It was obvious, but needed to be done in the right order for Apache with the appropriate `[L]` and `[R=301]`. I'll post it as the anwser right away.

Comment: You missed the change. You're still using `.*` instead of `[^/]+` which is why yours only works the other way around. Have you tried my answer, verbatim? You should always have your external redirects first.

Comment: Yes, I tried your answer verbatim and tested it conscientiously. It made itinfinite redirects.

Comment: What about now? I ran that on my dev server and it was flawless.

Comment: What a kick in the teeth. All that back-and-forth to get an optimal answer and not even an upvote.

Comment: Err.. Thanks again. And I did upvote you, of course!

Answer (score -1):

Here is the complete answer. The order is important.

```
RewriteEngine On
#########   Page rewriting  ########
RewriteRule ^fr/liste\.html$        /fr/liste.php [L]
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)\.html$         /fr/index.php?hash=$1 [L,B,QSA]
RewriteRule ^en/list\.html$         /en/list.php [L]
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)\.html$         /en/index.php?hash=$1 [L,B,QSA]
################ Redirect from root to /fr ################
RewriteRule ^$                      /fr [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^liste\.html$           /fr/liste.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$            /fr/$1.html [L,R=301]
```

This can still be condensed (see Walf's answer).

Comment: How does your last rule not redirect infinitely? `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /fr/$1.html [L,R=301]` matches `somehash.html` but also `en/somehash.html` and `en/fr/en/fr/cng/fy3/qo4ncg/6R$$%^/#CNO/.html`.

Comment: Because it's the last rule, and because all rules have `[L]` flags? I tested it and it's working in all cases. I can change `.*` to  `[^/]+` though, to be more exclusive.